# Недопустимая сигнатура типа

Tags: haskell

```
module People where

data Male = Man | Woman

class Human where
    Male2 :: Male

instance Human Male where
    Who :: Male -> String
    Who = if Male == Man
          then "Man"
          else "Woman
```

GHCI любезно кидает такую ошибку

```
People.hs:6:5: error:
    Invalid type signature: Male2 :: ...
    Should be of form <variable> :: <type>
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Дык вот не пойму, что не так. Знаниям языка не славлюсь, но все же где тут ошибиться можно было ума не приложу)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оказалось, что писать значение с маленькой буквы это не соглашение, а требования языка) Вот только теперь гадаю, как же написать сравнение для собственного типа...

Comment: `instance Eq` сделать.